# Font displays differently in different browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts

Why in FF text smaller (left) than in Chrome and Opera (right)?
(Font is Times New Roman Cyrillic and Text in Russian)

HTML:

```
 <div class="content block_width">
  <p>
     text
  <p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block_width{
    width: 1000px;
}

div.content{
    background-color: #F0F5F7;

    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    text-align:left;
}

p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman Cyr";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #636262;
}
```

[image]

Comment: use normalize.css : http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible explanations, but the most probable seems to be this: There is no font “Times New Roman Cyr”, at least from the viewpoint of some browsers. What happens in my rather ordinary computer (Win 7) is that Chrome ignores the font setting and uses its default font, whereas Firefox interprets “Times New Roman Cyr” as “Times New Roman”. You can check whether something similar happens in your system if you change the font setting to `font-family: "Times New Roman Cyr", Courier`, so that the very different font Courier will be used as backup.

Changing the setting to the following should help:

```
font-family:  "Times New Roman Cyr", "Times New Roman", serif
```

assuming that you expect Times New Roman Cyr to exist in some systems as different from Times New Roman and better than it.

Comment: It does not help. Still in FF font different from chrome and opera

Comment: @user1945604, then you need to provide more information. What are the actual fonts used in each browser?